# Consuming Kafka messages in Microservices

Tags: apache-kafka, event-handling, microservices, confluent-schema-registry

We have different services based on the domain. All these services communicate via Rest(Sync) and Kafka (async).

However, the writers of this service have used a common library to write the logic to consume the records from Kafka and individual services use this common library as dependency.

I believe this is an anti pattern of Microservices.

This is because all services have dependency on this common library, however the the library is getting the consumer record value as string(stringdeserializer) and then based on the type of the message content it is delegated to respective handler.

The common library is origin of event consumption, and deserialization is happening to string and then using Gson the string is converted to specific event types.

**The problem with above approach is that for schema evolution of the services is becoming bottleneck. As individual services are listening for  certain events on some topic, but everything is deserialized to string, hence unable to use schema registry for schema evolution**.

After many attempts i decided that common library is an evil for microservices as independency is killed.

Answer (score 1):

Who says the common library is needed? You could repeat all string parsing logic over and over in any new consumer to that topic.

So, that approach definitely isn't any better.

Your thoughts aren't unique to Kafka, or microservices, either. For example, a REST API uses Openapi and publishes a schema and client dependency. Any HTTP "consumer" needs to depend on that API and client, plus it's pinned at a specific version at runtime. If the API "producer" changes the server "events/schema", your "consumer" will fail.

The Schema Registry also makes a shared dependency, plus the overhead of maintaining an external service separate from the broker that must have higher availability than the brokers themselves, otherwise your clients will completely drop events. Also, Schema Registry supports custom types, so evolution can still happen, even for strings, albeit with much custom code.

If you want to store multiple types in one topic to use with Schema Registry, you'd use Subject naming strategies. Before that feature existed, though, the only way to do so was to create some switch-case in the consumer and wrap string/bytes data, such as CloudEvents object and annotate it with a type field.

Also worth pointing out - Kafka includes Jackson, so you shouldn't need Gson as an extra dependency

Comment: What i am thinking is that individual microservices consumes many events, so for each event is a topic and that evolves with topic as scope. I know there is one topic -> many events but I think i don't like that approach which is confusing. If an event is self sufficient and does not represent broad things event->topic can be one-to-one and one similar model should be defined to consume it but in my case all events are represent as common string which is composed in another wrapper and entire logic is in common library, so it is difficult for this model to evolve using schema registry

Comment: Wrapper types are more difficult to work with, but in that case, you will obviously need some parser logic which cannot guarantee backwards compatibility which the Registry would enforce since it cannot introspect "common string", only specifically typed/defined record fields.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here almost certainly isn't the common library, because you'd hit the same problem without it of producers and consumers needing to agree on a schema.  A schema registry makes it potentially easier to reach that agreement, but it doesn't really solve the problem (there are scenarios where the schema registry won't help you).

There are two deeper problems:

First (and this is almost certainly the bigger of the two), it sounds like you're using the same types as wire types (for interservice communication) and as internal model types.  This is what actually leads to the coupling.  By separating the wire types from the model types, you do incur the overhead of translation between them, but, "you don't get freedom for free" (Peart, 1976).  What you gain is only having to agree on the wire type which will change a lot less often than the internal model types as their respective services evolve.

Second, approaches to serialization that try to do things by magic based on implementation details of what you're serializing are intrinsically fragile.  This is perhaps less of a problem with a wire type, but defining the wire type in a "schema-first" manner might be useful.

Comment: In our project, Wire type is a wrapper POJO inside which another object is composed, this object is the actual event. Now entire wrapper along with object is string. So first wrapper is converted to POJO and then the composed object which is string is converted actual Event object using object mapper, i believe this is incorrect.
Individual services should use their own kafka consumer logic should consume event type per topic, not many events under one topic, 
is this correct?

Comment: No, it's not correct.

Comment: The events are sent on the wire: they're still wire types.

Comment: So lets say wire type has 10 fields, the internal model can pick and choose the fields it require, is that what you are suggesting? And you want to enforce schema on those 10 fields (wire type) ?
So a producer will serialize the 10 fields based on agreed schema for it and then consumer will deserialize the wire type (validates if it is same as producer?)  and pick and choose what it wants for internal model ?

But individual consumers will have their own needs so  schema enforcement on 10 fields makes no sense for consumers who do not need those 10 fields

Comment: @chebus It's not required for consumers to read all fields. In Avro, for example, you can define your reader schema to only have a subset of fields (using specific record reader), then the deserializer will project the data into that format for your consumer event payloads.